# How can I use phone numbers/phone directory for SEO

Tags: seo

I work for a company who help find people. I want to increase our SEO ranking by implementing phone numbers/directory on our site.

Main goal: If someone searches for a phone number, our site should be listed higher than where it lists now.

What can I implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [microformats](http://schema.org/docs/search_results.html#q=telephone). It helps to highlight details like telephone numbers and all major search engines support them.